# spawning multiple parallel tasks

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parallel-processing

I have M tasks to process and N parallel processing resources available (think worker threads on Heroko, or EC2 instances), where M >> N.

I could roll my own system, but it seems likely there's already a debugged package or gem for this: what do you recommend?  (Now that I think about it, I could torture Delayed::Job into doing this.)

The tasks can be written just about any language -- even a shell script will do the job.  The 'mother ship' is Ruby On Rails with a PostgreSQL database.  The basic idea is that when a resource is ready to process a task, it asks the mother ship for the next un-processed task in the queue and starts processing it.  If the job fails, it is re-tried a few times before giving up.  The results can go into flat files or be written into the PostgreSQL database.

*(And, no, this is not for generating spam.  I'm researching [degree distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_distribution) of several large social networks.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a delayed_job https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job or resque https://github.com/defunkt/resque job, as you said.

Comment: Agree. I don't understand why this solution would be considered "tortured."

Comment: I simply meant that there's a lot of details to attend to above and beyond the job processing that D::J or Resque offers, e.g. parceling out the tasks and dealing with errors.  But it's likely the way I'll go.

Comment: Accepting this answer.  In all likelihood, though, I'll use Amazon's SQS as part of the total work flow.

Answer (score 2):

This would be rolling your own, but but if your parallel task are not resource intensive, it is a reasonably quick solution. On the other hand, if they are resource intensive, you'll want to implement something much more robust.

You could start each thread with `Process::fork` (if the process is in ruby), or `Process::exec`, or `Process::spawn` (if the process is in something else). Then use `Process::waitall` for the sub-processes to complete.

Below, I used a `Hash` to hold the functions themselves as well as the PID's. This could definitely be improved on.

```
# define the sub-processes
sleep_2_fail = lambda { sleep 2; exit -1; }
sleep_2_pass = lambda { sleep 2; exit 0; }
sleep_1_pass = lambda { sleep 1; exit 0; }
sleep_3_fail = lambda { sleep 3; exit -1; }

# use a hash to store the lambda's and their PID's
sub_processes = Hash.new

# add the sub_processes to the hash
#  key = PID
#  value = lambda (can use to be re-called later on)
sub_processes.merge! ({ Process::fork { sleep_2_fail.call } => sleep_2_fail })
sub_processes.merge! ({ Process::fork { sleep_2_pass.call } => sleep_2_pass })
sub_processes.merge! ({ Process::fork { sleep_1_pass.call } => sleep_1_pass })
sub_processes.merge! ({ Process::fork { sleep_3_fail.call } => sleep_3_fail })

# starting time of the loop
start = Time.now

# use a while loop to wait at most 10 seconds or until
# the results are empty (no sub-processes)
while ((results = Process.waitall).count > 0 && Time.now - start < 10) do
  results.each do |pid, status|
    if status != 0
       # again add the { PID => lambda } to the hash
       sub_processes.merge! ( { Process::fork { sub_processes[pid].call } => sub_processes[pid] } )
    end
    # delete the original entry
    sub_processes.delete pid
  end
end
```

The [ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-waitall) on `waitall` is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a job processor.  Look at Gearman http://gearman.org/
Fairly language agnostic.

And here's the ruby Gem info http://gearmanhq.com/help/tutorials/ruby/getting_started/